# RPC Server Unavailable: Printing Word Doc in Python

Tags: python, printing, win32com, cpu-word, docxtpl

I am writing a Python program to print out a document. However, If I try to print something out a second time, I get an error stating 'RPC Server Unavailable"

Here is my code, using win32com and docxtpl

```
def printWordDocument(filename):
    word.Documents.Open(filename)
    word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut()
    time.sleep(2)
    word.ActiveDocument.Close()

def createDocument(n, a, z, c, nu):
    name = n
    addr = a
    csz = z
    court = c
    num = nu
    nup = n.upper()

    context = {'name': n, 'addr': a, 'csz': z, 'court': court, 'name_up': nup,
               'num': nu}
    
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save("C:\\Users\\mark\\Automations\\pt_generated.docx")
    printWordDocument("C:\\Users\\mark\\Automations\\pt_generated.docx")

def submitFunction():
    name = name_entry.get()
    addr = addr_entry.get()
    csz = csz_entry.get()
    court = csz_entry.get()
    num = num_entry.get()
    createDocument(name, addr, csz, court, num)
    word.Quit()
    os.remove("C:\\Users\\mark\\Automations\\pt_generated.docx")
    clearAddr()
```

The submitFunction() gets called first.

And this is the error I get when I try to print out something more than once:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mark\Automations\pt.py", line 98, in submitFunction
    word.Quit()
  File "<COMObject Word.Application>", line 2, in Quit
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None)
```

From the research I've done, it seems that this error is the result of a COM object not being properly released. However, I am calling word.Quit(), which should be releasing the document, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Solution: Turns out that the line `word.Quit()` was causing this. Once i removed it it worked.

Comment: In my experience Office products (especially Excel) are notorious for leaving tmp files around that can affect things. See if your directory is clean. Also you can try using a context manager or changing the filename to something unique for each pass to see if file locked or over-write issues. HTH

Comment: `createDocument` uses a variable `doc` which isn't set anywhere. What is it?

Comment: `doc = DocxTemplate("nwpt.docx")`